# Why can't my Javascript code access a div inside a google.maps.InfoWindow?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I'm using the Google Maps Javascript API. I'm setting the content of an InfoWindow to be a div. I then try to use  document.getElementById() to get the div element in the InfoWindow.

```
  var contentString = '<div id="content" style="width:200px;height:200px;"></div>';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      position: map.getCenter(),
      content: contentString
    });

  infowindow.open(map);

  console.log(document.getElementById('content'));
```

The InfoWindow shows up at the center of the map as I expect. However, the last line of my code here logs 'null' to the console. If I execute the same line of code within a different function after this code completes, an element is returned from getElementById('content') and info about the element is logged to the console. I don't understand what is happening here. I'd think that immediately after the code lines that create the InfoWindow and open it on the map that the 'content' div is part of the DOM. But running my code says otherwise. Anyone understand what's going wrong?

Comment: Because it's in a different frame.  Also, learn about the Same-Origin Policy.

Comment: Look at [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow) page, maybe the domready event could help you.

Comment: I don't believe the map is in a different frame. I didn't include the code that set up the map, but the entire map is contained in a div on my page, just as the Google Maps Javascript API directs me to do. Also if it was in a different frame, why would my later call to getElementById('content') succeed when the first one didn't?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the domready event. I assume that i wouldn't have to use that when I initially set the content of the InfoWindow, I'm guessing that it would be used to have one central spot in your script to handle any time the window gets displayed rather than having to repeat code everywhere in your script that could happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The infowindow content is added to the DOM asynchronously.  It is not available to get using `.getElementById` until after it is in the DOM.  To detect when it has been added to the DOM use the [`domready`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript//reference#InfoWindow) event on the infowindow:

> **domready** Arguments:  None
>
> This event is fired when the  containing the InfoWindow's content is attached to the DOM. **You may wish to monitor this event if you are building out your info window content dynamically.**

```
var contentString = '<div id="content" style="width:200px;height:200px;">14</div>';

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  position: map.getCenter(),
  content: contentString
});

infowindow.open(map);
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() {
    console.log(document.getElementById('content'));
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/voe4mcvr/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var contentString = '<div id="content" style="width:200px;height:200px;">14</div>';
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    content: contentString
  });
  infowindow.open(map);
  google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() {
    console.log(document.getElementById('content'));
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```